# How to use Jquery carousel() in Angularjs Controller.?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

How to make this code work in AngularJs.?

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval:100000
})
```

Comment: Add jQuery and carousel libraries with angular js.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a references to the libraries and file like:

```
<script src="jQuery.js"></script>
<script src="carousel.js"></script>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/carousel/code/file.js"></script>
```